# Undefined method field_changed? when trying to update attributes in Rails 3.2.12

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, update-attributes

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Rails 3.2.1 to 3.2.12 and am encountering a field_changed problem (method undefined) when trying to update attributes. I know it was changed to _field_changed in 3.2.9 and I think my gems are up-to-date, but I can't seem to find the issue. Any ideas? Here's my relevant code:

Controller

```
@user_role = Role.find_or_create_by_constituent_id(session[:user_id])
@user_role.update_attributes(:constituent_id => session[:user_id], :login => session[:username], :role => session[:user_role], :timestamp => Date.today)
@user_role.save
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem "composite_primary_keys"
gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.5.1"
gem "csv_builder", "~> 2.1.0"  #provides easy csv downloads
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :git => "git://github.com/timkleier/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.git", :ref => "6bfb3b59e1f0adef59c91ded519ae160fe28b386"
gem 'by_star', :git => "git://github.com/radar/by_star.git", :ref => "13b594c758"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem "less-rails"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "fog"
gem "figaro"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.2.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'jquery_datepicker'

gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
```

bundle show

```
  * actionmailer (3.2.12)
  * actionpack (3.2.12)
  * activemodel (3.2.12)
  * activerecord (3.2.12)
  * activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12 6bfb3b5)
  * activeresource (3.2.12)
  * activesupport (3.2.12)
  * annotate (2.5.0)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.4)
  * bundler (1.2.4)
  * by_star (2.0.0.beta1 13b594c)
  * capistrano (2.15.4)
  * carrierwave (0.8.0)
  * chronic (0.9.1)
  * client_side_validations (3.2.5)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
  * commonjs (0.2.6)
  * composite_primary_keys (5.0.8)
  * csv_builder (2.1.1)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.4)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * excon (0.6.6)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * figaro (0.6.4)
  * fog (0.9.0)
  * formatador (0.2.4)
  * highline (1.6.19)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.4)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * jquery_datepicker (0.4)
  * json (1.8.0)
  * less (2.3.2)
  * less-rails (2.3.3)
  * libv8 (3.11.8.17)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.23)
  * mini_portile (0.5.0)
  * multi_json (1.7.8)
  * net-scp (1.1.1)
  * net-sftp (2.1.2)
  * net-ssh (2.6.7)
  * net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
  * nokogiri (1.6.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.5)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (3.2.12)
  * rails_sql_views (0.8.0 be67a84)
  * railties (3.2.12)
  * rake (10.1.0)
  * rdoc (3.12.2)
  * ref (1.0.5)
  * rspec-core (2.13.1)
  * rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  * rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
  * rspec-rails (2.13.2)
  * ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
  * rvm-capistrano (1.3.1)
  * sass (3.2.9)
  * sass-rails (3.2.6)
  * spork (1.0.0rc3)
  * sprockets (2.2.2)
  * therubyracer (0.11.4)
  * thor (0.18.1)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * tiny_tds (0.5.1)
  * treetop (1.4.14)
  * twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.7)
  * tzinfo (0.3.37)
  * uglifier (1.2.7)
  * webrat (0.7.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out composite_primary_keys was the culprit. For whatever reason, bundle was using 5.0.8 and I needed to upgrade it to version 5.0.9 (where field_changed was changed to _field_changed).